# qBittorrent and auto unrar

Tags: rar, qbittorrent

How can I add command in qBittorrent to automatically extract compressed files after download is complete? I am new to Ubuntu and haven't gotten the hang of things quite yet.

Answer (score 3):

There's no specific Ubuntu man page for qbittorrent, but I did find the [home page](https://www.qbittorrent.org/), [FAQ](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki/Frequently-Asked-Questions), [wiki](https://github.com/qbittorrent/qBittorrent/wiki), and [support forum](https://qbforums.shiki.hu/).

The latter showed an option to *Run an external program on torrent completion* which would allow you to summon [7z](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man1/7z.1.html) or some other extraction app; 7z does just about all formats including ZIP and RAR, so that's my suggestion to use.  To install it, run `sudo apt update && sudo apt upgrade && sudo apt install p7zip-full` .

In Qbittorrent, choose **Options** then **Download** and check the tickbox for *Run an external program on torrent completion*, then give it an external CLI command line to extract the file, such as:  `7z x *`

Answer (score 3):

This works for me with p7zip (or p7zip-full) installed - **pay special attention to the -o section** where there is **no space** between it and the target directory. It took me 5-6 tries until I noticed that 7z uses this syntax format (without space) for most switches:

```
7z x "%F/*.rar" -o"%F/"
```

[image: command]

Answer (score 2):

Just wanted to put my two cents in here because the listed answers did not work for me. If you put the quotes after -o, it will potentially be interpreted as part of the path. Meaning you will be creating a grand new folder structure wherever your qBittorrent's working directory is, with the quotes being folder names in that structure, and extracting the files there. The correct way I found is with the opening quote BEFORE the -o (**FURTHER EDITS MADE SINCE THIS WAS POSTED, SEE BELOW**) :

```
7z x "%F/*.rar" "-o%F/"
```

I figured this out based on a comment [here](https://sourceforge.net/p/sevenzip/discussion/45797/thread/6be2fe8210/) which used a similar formatting for the -p parameter.

**EDITED DEC 2023:**
I recently had a torrent that had rar files nested inside of various subdirectories. The original command here does not account for that, I have come up with an improved version that does:

Create a .sh file with the following (may need to change perms to make it executable, however I didn't need to):

```
#!/bin/bash
find "$1/" -name "*.rar" -exec 7z x "{}" "-o$1/" -y \;
```

Set the qbittorrent field to (replace path/filename):

```
/path/to/script/TorrentExtraction.sh "%F"
```

This version will search the torrent directory & subdirectories for .rar files using find, and then pass each .rar file's full path into its own 7z command. I also added -y to bypass any prompts from 7z. I tried adding this command directly into qbittorrent, but I believe something with the -exec option for the find command was causing problems and the command did not execute. Qbittorrent is probably looking for a single execution, where the -exec option creates multiple.